# Is it possible that implementations based on same paper show different performance?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm a junior research engineer of AI.

Looking for the code in the particular paper, I found two git-hub repositories.
However, I think it's weird that how they show different performance, even though they are based on exact same paper and have a similar structure at the code level.
(Of course, I didn't compare the code line by line)

Is it possible, and common things?

Comment: Content of research is off-topic.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Yeah. I almost wrote an answer of my own, and then I went "wait a moment".

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, sorry, but I don't understand why you say this is about the "content of research". It seems to be about discrepancy of results.

Comment: "Different Performance" can mean a lot of things. What do you mean here, exactly. And was the performance reported or did you run the code yourself? And was it run on the same data? And is there a randomizer involved in any way?

Comment: @Buffy Resolving discrepancies in research results is a normal research activity.

Answer (score 10):

It's certainly possible. You just demonstrated that. (I assume you have compared implementations in the same language, compiled the same way.)

I don't think it's surprising. Implementing any reasonably complex algorithm calls for many choices that can affect performance to different degrees - choice of data structures and libraries, efficient use of space or memory.

Whether you should or want to compare the implementations "line by line" to ferret out the differences depends on how the difference in performance matters to you.

Comment: In particular, AI-related algorithms tend to make heavy use of linear algebra. This is an area where there is considerable scope for different implementations to have very different run-times. For example, the product of three non-square matrices A, B & C may have very different costs if computed as (AB)C or A(BC). This sort of optimisation is very easy to miss if just glancing over code, but can add up to substantial savings.

Comment: Using machine performance as a measure, it also requires being run on identical machines with the same operating system and with identical (or similar) loads.

Answer (score 4):

In the machine learning field, it is in fact surprising if you *could* manage to get similar results. Unfortunately, we are still far away from reproducible science. Authors do not disclose different parameters of their model and the tuning process and since many of the improvements are marginal, it is quite possible that a small tweak in the results causes the performance to decline drastically.

Comment: Yes, model parameters can make a huge difference. Some models are shipped with sensible default parameters, others aren't. If one of the two implementations used a better parameter that can make a big difference. One strategy could be to use another algorithm to optimize the model configuration, that could reduce the difference in performance between the two implementations.

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly possible. A simple example is, perhaps one code is [parallelized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing) and the other isn't. More technical differences could be, perhaps one code uses X method to perform numerical integration and the other uses Y, and X is better than Y for small datasets and inferior for larger ones.

As for whether it's common, I imagine it's uncommon for complex codes to have the same performance. That's how one can tell they're written independently.